# REST API OData Filter on Boolean not Working

Tags: 2013, filter, rest

When I perform a REST query to the following URL:
`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('BtProjects')/items?$filter=Active eq true` 
I receive only the one item that has this field marked as `false`. I get the same result when regarless of whete I use `eq true` or `eq false`. Anyone have any suggestions for a work-around? This is on prem SP1 and my understanding is that this issue does not appear on SP Online, but I've not verified that.

Comment: This does work just fine on SP Online; have you tried using 'true' (with the single quotes)?

Comment: I can replicate in SP Online.  Filtering for `field eq true` or `field eq 'true'` returns items where field is false.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try using 1 for true, 0 for false.  I was able to replicate your problem in SPO, but using 1/0 worked fine:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('BtProjects')/items?$filter=Active eq 1
```

Comment: That does indeed work!

Comment: I was trying with 'true' & 'yes', but didn't thought about 1/0. This did the job, well done!

Answer (score 5):

I thought I had already tried `Active ne false` but I guess I had not. That seems to work. It looks like the `eq` filter is broken for booleans, though.

Comment: This solution works better when existing items may not have a value for the field.  Not relative to the question, but a good thing to know.

Comment: Not broken, just uses 0/1 instead.

Comment: @hamboy that's why the accepted answer is what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Booleans are still broken when using SharePoint Online and the REST API. As of this writing, using 1/0 and true/false do not function as expected. When I tested, it actually returned the FULL dataset and ignored my $filter parameter.

Instead, I just created a choice column (with yes/no as options) and switched to that:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('BtProjects')/items?$filter=Active eq 'Yes'
```

Comment: Still broken  as of today as well @Jiffy

Comment: mine worked, I have a yes/no column and I used 1/0 in the $filter

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work using the methods described by wjervis and Robert recommended, but only when the bool field was the first filter term like below. Another thing to note is that the bool field can be null although the odata readout may show a true or false for the field.

```
/_api/ProjectData/Resources()?$filter=checkBool eq true & ResourceEmailAddress ne null
```